# continuity of $f ' $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ can we say that $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$?

I tried some functions and it seems that we can say so but I'm not sure.

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}),& x\neq 0\\ 0,& x=0\end{array}\right.$$